# Splitting vector in dataframe into 2 vectors

Tags: r

I need to split a vector in a dataframe(last.first) into 2 separate vectors (firstname, lastname) and then put the 2 vectors back into the dataframe. What should I do.

Comment: Take a look at the `cSplit` function in my "splitstackshape" package.

Comment: Take a look at `separate` from `tidyr`.

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can split names with `strsplit`, use whatever is separating the first and second names instead of `" "` (space in my example).

This will give you a list. Which can be made into dataframe via `ldply` or `unlist` to `matrix`

```
person.names <- c("Adam Smith", "Max Webber")
temp.list <- strsplit(person.names, " ")
names.df <- ldply(temp.list, function (x) data.frame(first = x[1], second = x[2]))


  first second
1  Adam  Smith
2   Max Webber
```

or

```
matrix(unlist(temp.list), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```